# How to merge properties of two types with properties overlap?

Tags: typescript

Input: two types, output: third type that has properties of first type overlaped with props of second (like merge/assign) works on object properties.

```
type X = {
  a: string,
  b: string
}

type Y = {
  b: number,
  d: number
}
// how to type get type Z that is "merge" of X & Y so that:
let z: Z

z.a => string
z.b => number
z.d => number
```

`Z = X & Y` gives that  z.a => string, z.b => string | number (I want it be just number)

Comment: `Z = X & Y` will give `z.b => string & number`. Is that what are you expecting?

Comment: `z.b` is not `string`, it is `string & number` (which doesn't make much sense). There probably isn't a good way to do what you want. You'll either need to define your types differently so that you can create `Z` using intersection, or define `Z` without intersection

Comment: Ok is it possible to make it number for this case?

Comment: Sure, as @NitzanTomer mentioned, define Z without intersection: `type Z { a: string, b: number, d: number; }` or change the types: `type X = { a: string }; type Y = { b: number, d: number }; type Z = X & Y;`

Comment: Good joke. I have two types to derived type of these two with a certain properties.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript does not support this. You can take a look at mixins: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html. This is the closest I found to what you want, but it still does not solve your problem:

```
class X {
    a: number;
    b: number;
}

class Y {
    a: string;
    d: number;
}

class Z implements X, Y {
    a: any;   // Note how I was need to make "any" type here to make it work
    b: number;
    d: number;
}
applyMixins(Z, [Y, X]);   // Read provided link for documentation for this function

let x: X = { a: 2, b: 2 };
let y: Y = { a: '2', d: 2 };
let z: Z = { a: 'x', b: 2, d: 2 };
```